# How to run a certain method every time a button is clicked with changing buttons in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, do-while

I want to be able to run the content() method every time a button is clicked with the id of the button as the parameter. This method removes the old buttons and displays new buttons.

This is the code I have so far:

```
do {
    selection = $('button').click(function() {return this.id;});
    content(selection);
} while(selection !== "end");
```

Comment: Title and question do not correspond.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a click event handler where you call the `content` method

```
$('button').click(function () {
    content(this.id);
});
```

---

If you want to execute the same method again when the replaced button is clicked then you need to use event delegation

```
$(document).on('click', 'button', function () {
    content(this.id);
});
```

Comment: you need to bind click event again because in content method he will replace the button dom.

Comment: @PushkerYadav may not be required because OP may just want to replace the old buttons... else event delegation is the best option

Comment: I used the second way and it is now working. Thank you!